# What are the names for the following “anti-ideal”-like properties?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, ideals, semigroups

Let $C$ be a semigroup (or analogously a category). A family $A ⊆ C$ is called

- *subsemigroup* if $a, b ∈ A \implies ab ∈ A$,

  *left ideal* if $b ∈ A \implies ab ∈ A$ (analogously we define right ideal and two-sided ideal).

**Question**: Are there names for the following properties?

1. $ab ∈ A \implies b ∈ A$ (think of $A$ consisting of injective maps $X \to X$ and $S$ consisting of all maps; in general the family of all monomorphisms in a category have the property),

   $ab ∈ A ∧ a ∈ A \implies b ∈ A$ (think of $A$ consisting of distance preserving maps $X \to X$ on a metric space and $S$ consisting of all maps)?

*Added*: When $C$ is a is trivial preoder on a set $X$ (i.e. every two elements are comparable) viewed as a category, then $A ⊆ C$ corresponds to a binary relation on $X$, and the property 2. corresponds to the notion of Euclidean relation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_relation).

Comment: Just a thought, but $ab \in A \implies (a\in A \lor b\in A)$ is the crucial property in $A$ being *prime* (as an ideal, in ring theory).

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg True, so maybe calling 1. *left-prime* would be a meaningful name if nothing standard exists.

Comment: When a (commutative) multiplicative set has the property that $ab\in A\implies a\in A$, it's called *saturated* (and of course $b\in A$ as well at that point.) Now, your definition seems to be phrased for a noncommutative context, but one could justify calling 1) "right saturated." or something

Comment: @rschwieb I think that with a coset, the situation is different. $ab ∈ gH$ and $a ∈ gH$ gives $b ∈ H$, not desired $b ∈ gH$. Though it works for the subgroup $H$ itself.

Comment: @user87690 Of course, yes :)  I got distracted by cosets and should have just said "subgroup."

Comment: A good example of 2) is a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$. (corrected from an earlier attempt.)

Answer (score 2):

According to Dubreil [2] (see also Clifford and Preston [1, p. 55]), a subset satisfying (2) is called *left unitary*.

For (1), recall that the preorder Green relation $\leqslant_\mathcal{L}$ is defined by
$x \leqslant_\mathcal{L} b$ (read "$x$ is $\cal L$-below $b$") if and only if there exists $c \in C \cup \{1\}$ such that $x = cb$. Thus (1) means that $A$ is a *$\leqslant_\mathcal{L}$-upper set*.

[1] A. H. Clifford and G. B. Preston, The algebraic theory of semigroups. Vol. II. Mathematical Surveys, No. 7. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 1967. xv + 350 pp.

[2] P. Dubreil, Contribution à la théorie des demi-groupes. *Mém. Acad. Sci. Inst. France* (2) **63** (1941), no. 3, 52 pp